# Using the Google Drive API for PHP, What is the proper way to upload a file while setting the "keepRevisionForever" to true?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to allow file uploads to overwrite the previous copy and keep the revision history permanent within Google Drive.  Also...Do I need to upload with a set ID or is the file name going to overwrite natively?

Here is a sample of what I have as a test function:

```
function uploadFile($filename = "")
{
    
    $title="testFile";
    $description="Testing the upload of the file";
    $mimeType="image/jpeg";
    $filename = ROOTPATH."IMG_1232.JPG"; //Temporarily overriding $filename for testing.
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setName($title);
    $file->setDescription($description);
    $file->setMimeType($mimeType);

    // Set the parent folder.
    if ($parentId != null) {
        $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
        $parent->setId($parentId);
        $file->setParents(array($parent));
    }

    try {
        $data = file_get_contents($filename);
        
        $this->startGDService();
        
        $createdFile = $this->service->files->create($file, array(
            'data' => $data,
            'mimeType' => $mimeType,
            'keepRevisionForever' => true //  <---This doesn't seem to work.
            ));

        return $createdFile;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was using the wrong function.  The create function will always create a file on the drive.  To overwrite a particular file, you need to use the update() function.  See here:

```
function updateFile($filename, $fileID)
{
    $this->startGDService();
    $filename = UPLOAD_PATH.$filename;
    $mimetype = mime_content_type ($filename);
    try {
        $emptyFile = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $data = file_get_contents($filename);
        $this->service->files->update($fileID, $emptyFile, array(
            'data' => $data,
            'mimeType' => $mimetype,
            'uploadType' => 'multipart',
            'keepRevisionForever' => true
        ));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```